# PowerApps: getting most recent record having a condition

Tags: sharepoint, powerapps

Is it possible in PowerApps to get at the latest record, from a SharePoint list, having a certain condition?
In my case I know how to get the number, using something like this:

```
CountIf(Applications, Status = "Pending")
```

But, I would also like to get the most recent one of them. Well I suppose that would imply two conditions where the second is a Date column, but is it possible to sort it and then pick the first? Grateful for any guidance...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can use an expression that [sorts](https://learn.microsoft.com/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/functions/function-sort) the [filtered](https://learn.microsoft.com/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/functions/function-filter-lookup) data source by the date in descending order, and take the [first](https://learn.microsoft.com/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/functions/function-first-last) element, like in the expression below:

```
First(
    SortByColumns(
        Filter(Applications, Status = "Pending"),
        "DateColumn",
        Descending))
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Will check this out and be back soon!

Comment: Splendido! Works perfectly! Thank you once again! :-)